# Can Siri be used with a Cordova app?

Tags: xcode, html, cordova, siri

Is it possible to use Siri with a Cordova app or only with the native apps?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [cordova-plugin-speech-recognition-feat-siri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-speech-recognition-feat-siri) will help you